Why my def perform_update() doesn't work in Django rest framwrok?
i want when user update a data of leave request django will send email to supervisor of that user
perform_create is work but perform_update don't work
Here's my code that's problem
        def perform_update(self, serializer):
            with transaction.atomic():
                try:
                    leave_request = serializer.instance
                    serializer.save()
                    supervisor = leave_request.user.supervisor
                    if supervisor and supervisor.email:
                        self.send_leave_request_email(leave_request, supervisor.email, "Updated Leave Request")
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error(f"Error during leave request update: {str(e)}")
                    raise e

Here's CLass
class LeaveRequestList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        serializer_class = leave_requestsSerializer

        def get_queryset(self):
                queryset = leave_requests.objects.all()
                location = self.request.query_params.get('location')
                if location is not None:
                    queryset = queryset.filter(testLocation=location)
                return queryset

        def perform_create(self, serializer):
            with transaction.atomic():
                try:
                    leave_request = serializer.save()
                    supervisor = leave_request.user.supervisor
                    if supervisor and supervisor.email:
                        self.send_leave_request_email(leave_request, supervisor.email, "Leave Request")
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error(f"Error during leave request creation: {str(e)}")
                    raise e
                    
        def perform_update(self, serializer):
            with transaction.atomic():
                try:
                    leave_request = serializer.instance
                    serializer.save()
                    supervisor = leave_request.user.supervisor
                    if supervisor and supervisor.email:
                        self.send_leave_request_email(leave_request, supervisor.email, "Updated Leave Request")
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error(f"Error during leave request update: {str(e)}")
                    raise e


        def send_leave_request_email(self, leave_request, supervisor_email, subject):
            try:
                datetime_start_formatted = leave_request.datetime_start.strftime("Date: %d %B %Y Time: %I:%M:%S %p")
                datetime_end_formatted = leave_request.datetime_end.strftime("Date: %d %B %Y Time: %I:%M:%S %p")
                duration = (leave_request.datetime_end - leave_request.datetime_start)
                days = duration.days
                hours, remainder = divmod(duration.seconds, 3600)
                minutes, _ = divmod(remainder, 60)
                first_name = leave_request.user.first_name
                last_name = leave_request.user.last_name    

                email_html_message = f"""
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                    <title>{subject}</title>
                    <style>
                        body {{
                            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                            background-color: #f4f4f4;
                            margin: 0;
                            padding: 0;
                        }}
                        .container {{
                            max-width: 800px;
                            margin: 0 auto;
                            padding: 20px;
                            background-color: #fff;
                            border-radius: 10px;
                            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                        }}
                        h1 {{
                            color: #333;
                        }}
                        p {{
                            color: #555;
                        }}
                        .details {{
                            margin-top: 20px;
                            padding-top: 10px;
                            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
                        }}
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="container">
                        <h1>{subject}</h1>
                        <p>Intern <strong>{first_name} {last_name}</strong> has requested leave:</p>
                        <div class="details">
                            <p><strong>Requested Period:</strong> <strong>[ {datetime_start_formatted} ]</strong> to <strong>[ {datetime_end_formatted} ]</strong></p>
                            <p><strong>Duration:</strong> {days} days, {hours} hours, {minutes} minutes</p>
                            <p><strong>Type of Leave:</strong> {leave_request.get_type_of_leave_display()}</p>
                            <p><strong>Reason:</strong> {leave_request.description}</p>
                            <p><strong>Contact:</strong> {leave_request.tel}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
                </html>
                """
                send_mail(
                    f"{subject} from {first_name} {last_name}",
                    "",
                    "VANMAN System <your-email@example.com>",
                    [supervisor_email],
                    html_message=email_html_message,
                    fail_silently=False,
                )
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error sending leave request email: {str(e)}")
                raise e
    
        def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                # Delete all instances of leave_requests
                leave_requests.objects.all().delete()
                return Response({'message': 'All leave_requests deleted successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
            except Exception as e:
                return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)


The perform_update(...) method is being called from either from update(...) or partial_update(...) method during an update operation. The ListCreateAPIView class is not for update operation.

function perform_update is called in method update that is provided in the mixin class UpdateModelMixin. So your view class should inherit from this mixin too.
class LeaveRequestList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                       mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                       mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                        GenericAPIView):
    ## Rest of your code

